# using gets(str) in C

Tags: c

Im trying to use `gets(str)` in my code 
here is my code

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int i; //item number
    char coins[100]; //getting coins using get(str)
    printf("(Item#  ItemName   ItemPrice)\n");
    printf("1.     Water       0.55TL\n");
    printf("2.     Cola        0.55TL\n");
    printf("3.     Fanta       0.55TL\n");
    printf("4.     Chocolate   0.55TL\n");
    printf("5.     Biscuit     0.55TL\n");
    printf("6.     Gum         0.55TL\n");
    printf("7.     Candy       0.55TL\n");
    printf("Enter your selection item => ");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("Your choice is %d", i);
    printf("\nEnter coins => ");
    gets(coins);
    printf("\nYou have entered: %s coins", coins);


    return 0;   
    }
```

actually program suppose to ask 2 inputs as one is item number (digit) and another one is coins that user had entered. To make sure the program is working right i try to print those `i` and `couns` but program asking only 1 input and assigning that input to both `couns` and `i` depend on char or integer that i have entered. 
 Whats wrong with this code ? what should i do to separate those coins and item number? 
 Sorry for my bad english but i think u got what i mean 
 Thanks

Comment: `gets` does not check if there is enough space to save input, so you may have troubles with memory. Using `gets` is unsafe, don't to this.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&i);` : remain `'\n'`. It has been consumed by `gets`. try   `scanf(" %99[^\n]", coins);` instead `gets`.

Comment: But in homework i have to use `gets(str)`

Comment: and moreover the user will enter several coins at once so i need to get that input as string like 50 10 5 etc coins will be entered

Comment: thanks scanf(" %99[^\n]", coins); this one is woking well :)

Comment: `gets` cannot be used safely. In fact, it's been removed from the language as of the 2011 ISO C standard. But in your case (`char coins[100];` ... `gets(coins);`, it won't cause any problems as long as you're careful not to give it more than 100 characters of input. I *hope* your instructor is planning to cover this later.

Comment: @user3371196: If you are forced to use `gets()` in homework, it's time you step up to your instructor and tell him he's teaching the wrong thing. `gets()` is *deprecated* because it's *broken by design*. It's like teaching people to light their BBQ using ethyl alcohol until they're ready to use proper lighting aids.

Comment: didnt forced :) but he mentioned that we can use `gets()` and i dont know other commands yet thats why i wanted to use command that teacher offered

Comment: @user3371196: `man fgets`. Just take care of the trailing newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally , `gets` its a bad way to read strings. If you want so, you have to know that gets reads ENTER Key a string, which scanf translates as a '\n' char, so after `scanf("%d",&i);` command, `gets(coins)` reads as next string the character returned from ENTER key pressed, so in your programm, all you have to do is to place an extra `gets(coins) command before the existing gets you already have.

your programm should be like this

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int i; //item number
    char coins[100]; //getting coins using get(str)
    printf("(Item#  ItemName   ItemPrice)\n");
    printf("1.     Water       0.55TL\n");
    printf("2.     Cola        0.55TL\n");
    printf("3.     Fanta       0.55TL\n");
    printf("4.     Chocolate   0.55TL\n");
    printf("5.     Biscuit     0.55TL\n");
    printf("6.     Gum         0.55TL\n");
    printf("7.     Candy       0.55TL\n");
    printf("Enter your selection item => ");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("Your choice is %d", i);
    printf("\nEnter coins => ");

    gets(coins); //extra gets 
    gets(coins);
    printf("\nYou have entered: %s coins", coins);


    return 0;   
}
```